# Adding layout under QStackedWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can i add different layouts under `QStackedWidget`. I have 3 `QVBoxLayout` and i want to add this `QVBoxLayout` under `QStackedWidget`. I know layout cant add inside widget. but is there is any way to do that. So that from `QStackedWidget` i can change different `layout`.

```
mywindow::mywindow() : QMainWindow()
{   
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    layout1 = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
    layout2 = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout3 = new QVBoxLayout();

    stack1 = new QStackedWidget();
    list1 = new QListWidget();
    list2 = new QListWidget();
    list3 = new QListWidget();
    label1 = new QLabel("Main Menu");
    label2 = new QLabel();
    label3 = new QLabel("Hello");
    label4 = new QLabel("Hi");
    line1 = new QLineEdit();

    list1->addItem("Item 1");
    list1->addItem("Item 2");
    list1->addItem("Item 100");

    list2->addItem("Item 3");
    list2->addItem("Item 4");

    list3->addItem("Item 5");
    list3->addItem("Item 6");


    layout1->addWidget(label1);
    layout1->addWidget(list1);
    layout1->addWidget(label2);

    layout2->addWidget(label3);
    layout2->addWidget(list2);

    layout3->addWidget(label4);
    layout3->addWidget(list3);

    stack1->addWidget(layout1);
    stack1->addWidget(layout2);
    stack1->addWidget(layout3);

    this->setLayout(layout);

}
```

Comment: don't use a `QStackedWidget` at all?

Comment: But i want to switch from one layout to other. So i am using QStackedWidget.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create 3 `QWidget` objects, add each layout to each of the widgets and then add the widgets to the stacked widget.

Comment: use a different layout than `layout1` for the centralWidget. btw you need to put the stackedwidget in the centralwidget layout.

Comment: I used different Layout for mainLayout. But not getting the result as it is throwing an error as "Attempting to set Layout which already has a layout.

Comment: yes you are. your code is `layout1 = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);`, should be `layout1 = new QVBoxLayout()`